# How to detect Alt+A reliably across browsers and keyboard layouts?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, keypress, keydown

I haven't been able to find a reliable way of detecting shortcuts such as `Alt+A` reliably.

If I listen to `keydown` the `keyCode` property refers to the actual keyboard key, not necessarily the character that's printed on it, so I can't use it to reliably detect if the character being pressed is actually an `a`.

I can use `keypress` for detecting if an actual `a` is being pressed, but once I press `Alt+A` than keypress tells me that `å` has been inserted, and I can't reliably infer the actual key being used from that.

Is this impossible to do?

Comment: Alt-a, at least in latest firefox on windows 10, does not trigger keypress, so, not sure what you're seeing - however, if you look at keydown events you should see something more useful - though, if your system has some keyboard "magic" that maps Alt-A to `å` then you may be out of luck anyway

Comment: `Element.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.altKey && e.key === 'a' || e.key === 'A'){
    console.log(e.key);
  }
}`

Comment: it also works on keyup @PHPglue :p

Comment: This is funny though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey

Comment: @JaromandaX Alt+A triggers a keypress for me under macos + chrome. There's no magic involved, just the default macos behavior.

Comment: @PHPglue doesn't work for me, when I do a `Alt-A` then `e.key === 'å'`.

Comment: Make sure you have your charset set correctly. `<meta charset='UTF-8' />` in your `<head>`.

Comment: I guess macos isn't windows :p so you'll find that while macos does one thing with that key combination, windows does something different, and Linux probably different again ... what does macos report when using `keydown` instead of `keypress` - if that is also `å` then you're basically out of luck. A browser gets what the operating system sends it

Comment: @PHPglue the charset is set properly.

Comment: @JaromandaX on keydown I get `key: "å"` and `code: "KeyA"`. I've found that mousetrap [0] can reliably detect this for me, even when switching to the AZERTY layout, I'm not quite sure how it does it though. [0] https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap

Comment: `code: "KeyA"` that's good then

Comment: @JaromandaX no because that's layout independent, if I switch from QWERTY to AZERTY I still get `KeyA`, because the key is the same, but under the AZERTY layout that key types `q`.

Comment: well, then, there's no solution if your operating system sends that

Comment: @JaromandaX since mousetrap seems to handle this just fine there seems to be a solution.

Comment: Yep. Use mousetrap